# How can I adjust the columns after initializing server-side processing datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable, server-side, adjustment

When my server-side processing datatable is loaded the header is broken. To resolve this, I added `table.columns.adjust().draw()` to my initComplete function:

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
   "serverSide": true,
   /// more code...
   "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
       table.columns.adjust().draw();
   }
});
```

This works, but it affected the pagination. The correct page is not displayed anymore. It is set back to to first page. How can I prevent this?

Comment: What DataTables version are you using?

Comment: DataTables 1.10.19

Comment: and  DataTables Bootstrap 3 integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DataTables version > 1.10.x, you can simply pass `false` to [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) api which will redraw the table but maintaining current paging position like:

```
table.columns.adjust().draw( false );
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()):

- `paging` false

  - the ordering and search will be recalculated and the rows redrawn in their new positions. The paging will **not** be reset - i.e. the current page will still be shown.

Comment: Oh thank you so great! I was searching so mucg for a solution, how did you know that?

Comment: I have been using datatable for past few years :) I have also added docs links.